# Modified Parallel Scan

Tags: parallel-processing, gpgpu

This is more of an algorithms question than a programming one.  I'm wondering if the prefix sum (or any) parallel algorithm can be modified to accomplish the following.  I'd like to generate a result from two input lists on a GPU in less than O(N) time.

The rule is:  Carry forth the first number from data until the same index in keys contains a lesser value.

Whenever I try mapping it to a parallel scan, it doesn't work because I can't be sure which values of data to propagate in upsweep since it's not possible to know which prior data might have carried far enough to compare against the current key.  This problem reminds me of a ripple carry where we need to consider the current index AND all past indices.

Again, don't need code for a parallel scan (though that would be nice), more looking to understand how it can be done or why it can't be done.

```
int data[N] = {5, 6, 5, 5, 3, 1, 5, 5};
int keys[N] = {5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5};
int result[N];

serial_scan(N, keys, data, result);
// Print result.  should be {5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, }
```

code to do the scan in serial is below:

```
void serial_scan(int N, int *k, int *d, int *r)
{
  r[0] = d[0];
  for(int i=1; i<N; i++) 
    {
      if (k[i] >= r[i-1]) {
        r[i] = r[i-1];
      } else if (k[i] >= d[i]) {
        r[i] = d[i];
      } else {
        r[i] = 0;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general technique for a parallel scan can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29304719/Papers/lecture05%20%281%29.pdf), described in the functional language Standard ML. This can be done for any associative operator, and I think yours fits the bill.

One intuition pump is that you can calculate the sum of an array in O(log(n)) span (running time with infinite processors) by recursively calculating the sum of two halves of the array and adding them together. In calculating the scan you just need know the sum of the array before the current point.

We could calculate the scan of an array doing two halves in parallel: calculate the sum of the 1st half using the above technique. Then calculating the scan for the two halves sequentially; the 1st half starts at 0 and the 2nd half starts at the sum you calculated before. The full algorithm is a little trickier, but uses the same idea.

Here's some pseudo-code for doing a parallel scan in a different language (for the specific case of ints and addition, but the logic is identical for any associative operator):

```
//assume input.length is a power of 2

int[] scanadd( int[] input) {
  if (input.length == 1)
    return input 
  else { 
    //calculate a new collapsed sequence which is the sum of sequential even/odd pairs 
    //assume this for loop is done in parallel

    int[] collapsed = new int[input.length/2]
    for (i <- 0 until collapsed.length) 
      collapsed[i] = input[2 * i] + input[2*i+1]

    //recursively scan collapsed values
    int[] scancollapse = scanadd(collapse)

    //now we can use the scan of the collapsed seq to calculate the full sequence

    //also assume this for loop is in parallel
    int[] output = int[input.length]
    for (i <- 0 until input.length) 
      //if an index is even then we can just look into the collapsed sequence and get the value
      // otherwise we can look just before it and add the value at the current index

      if (i %2 ==0) 
        output[i] = scancollapse[i/2]
      else 
        output[i] = scancollapse[(i-1)/2] + input[i]

    return output
  } 
}
```